# Repopulating Scraped Table Data Via Web Source Based on a Cell Input (from a Barcode Scanner)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, vba

I am scraping the table data from a sports card authentication site (e.g. psacard.com/cert/25819397/) that encapsulates every card in acrylic and has a unique barcode with a web source table import. [Card Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrEtq.png) I am creating a product csv with the results.

Now cards are very time consuming to list because they have many important attributes that all must be typed out, so from that scrape I then map the returned fields to my product csv [Table Data Returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1juRo.png) and then add them together so I have to input as little data as possible. I take the returned brand, year, and player and make a product's imported title "player + year + brand" to import into woocommerce or ebay. I do similar things for the rest of the fields. Delimited text is my comfort zone.

What I am trying to figure out is how best to take the rs232 scanner data which automatically enters scanned data as text plus a terminator and populate each line of my product database with data pulled from the scrape.

1) Is the Excel web data source manipulable at all with a VBA script, or do I need a purely macro based solution for fetching/scraping the data once a scan inputs a serial number in a cell?

2) Is it even possible to trigger such a long chain of events with a scan reliably in Excel?

I guess I am stuck conceptually here. I have many possible deep rabbit holes for each segment of the task. I don't know where I should invest my time first. The site does not return JSON or XML with any RESTful request as there is no available API. It's tables or bust which makes me useless programmatically without javascript.

Comment: http://bensullins.com/hacking-excel-web-queries/

Found this. Seems possible to make web query work. Will post results when found. 

So once this works the next stage is to make this query run every cell that gets data, and to generate sequentially the rows for the product list.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJ30U0qw850

It needs some scripting of the operations, but that is fairly straightforward. The logic is worked out.

1) Scan card, which enters integer (barcode) on a predefined cell.

2) That cell triggers automatically refreshing web query like the one described in the video.

3) A table populated by the web query is called by another table which joins/edits/formats the variable data as a product list row.

4) A macro listens for a change in the original cell data to make the next row become the live row for input.